# First Element as pivot in Quick sort

Tags: c#, c++, algorithm

Why this code gives me wrong ? In Quick sort , I have picked up the first element as pivot:

I have traced that on paper,nothing is wrong.

```
    private void QuickSort(ref int [] S ,int l,int h)
    {
        //partioning
        int pivot_index = l;
        int j = 0;
        int temp = 0;
        for(int i=l+1;i<=h;i++)
            if (S[pivot_index] > S[i])
            {
                j++;
                temp = S[i];
                S[i] = S[j];
                S[j] = temp;
            }
        pivot_index = j;
        temp = S[l];
        S[l] = S[j];
        S[j] = temp;
        //end partioning

        if (l < h && pivot_index>l && pivot_index<h)
        {
            QuickSort(ref S, l, pivot_index - 1);
            QuickSort(ref S, pivot_index + 1, h);
        }
    }
```

here is my main :

```
        int[] List = get_input(textBox1.Text, ref n);
        //
        QuickSort(ref List, 0, n-1);
```

Comment: Why are you passing your arrays by reference? Arrays are already reference types.

Comment: Isn't this pure C# code? Why the C++ tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is apparently supposed to sort `[l, h]` range in the array, yet for some reason you are swapping element number `i` with element number `j`. The latter (`j`) is out of `[l, h]` range (it is always initially 0 and then it becomes 1, 2, 3 and so on). What are you trying to do by this? Why are you swapping your elements to some totally unrelated remote location out of your sorting range?

In other words this does not even remotely look like a QuickSort-style sorting algorithm to me. Your unexplainable manipulations with `j` is one reason why your implementation cannot really sort anything.

Comment: nice thing  , yes , should to set j=l;

Comment: Even then, the algorithm is still wrong. You must search a `S[i]` from left to right and a `S[j]` from right to left. This will require three loops in total. One to search for `i`, one to search for `j` and one which encloses the search-swap process. See my answer for details.

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes: The algorithm is not "wrong" and there's no "must" there. The technique with moving two indexes towards each other from opposite ends of the range is clever and efficient, however there's absolutely no requirement to do it that way specifically. The array has to be partitioned. That's the only "must" here. How is this partitioning implemented is completely irrelevant. What the OP is doing is a perfectly valid approach. It could be inefficient, but still perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is wrong. Get the pivot value `int pivot = S[pivot_index];`.

Then determine the two elements that you want to swap. Therefore, determine the first element from the left, which is greater than or equal to the pivot value. This gives `i`. Then determine the first element from the right, which is less than or equal to the pivot value. This gives `j`. As long as `i` is less than `j` swap `S[i]` and `S[j]` and repeat the process.

Only after there are no more swaps to make, look if you can call QuickSort recursively. Here two separate `if` checks must be made for the left part and the right part.

---

Also, note that it is better to take the element in the middle as pivot element. QuickSort will perform better, if the elements should be pre-sorted or sorted in descending order.

```
int pivot = S[(l+h)/2];
```

Comment: A median of three+ is significantly faster than picking the middle, if you're going to make suggestions for how he picks the median,

Comment: @Mooing Duck: Strictly speaking, the practical evidence of the usefulness of the "median of three" method is virtually nonexistent.

Comment: @AndreyT: Picking the middle will be on average 25% from the mean.  Median of three will be on average ~21%.  That's ~20% closer to the real mean, leading to less depth, which can have a big impact.  It also halves the depth of the worst case.  And [in my tests](http://ideone.com/Nruol) it's faster and uses less comparisons for more than 600ish elements.  But I admit, it _is_ more complicated, and (at best) only about 8% faster.